# Не получается редактировать запись в MySQL php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Сколько времени копался, так и не смог разобраться. Не редактируются данные в базе MySQL. Есть автоинкремент переменная id, не могу сообразить, как связаться с ней и изменить определенную запись в таблице. Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Edit</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Edit</h2>
  <form  name = "editform" action="editdata.php" method="post">
<p>
  <label>Имя:<br></label>
  <input type="text" name ="Name" size="20" maxlength="20"> 
</p>
<p>
  <label>Фамилия:<br></label>
  <input type="text" name ="LastName" size="30" maxlength="30"> 
</p>
<p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Сохранить изменения">
</p>
</form>

<?php
  require_once  'connection.php';
    $db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)
      or die("Error".mysqli_error($db));
        mysqli_select_db($db, "mysql");

  if(@$_POST['submit'])     
  {
    $Name = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['Name'])); 
    $LastName = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['LastName']));
    $query ="UPDATE users SET  Name = '$Name', LastName='&LastName' WHERE id = '$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die("ERROR" . mysqli_error($db)); 
    if($result)
      echo "<span style='color:red;'>Изменения сохранены</span>";
  }

?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: если вы редактируете какую-то запись, то id нужно передавать через скрытое поле, а-ля `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="...""/>`, а чтобы всю эту шляпу с подобием экранирования не писать, используйте подготовленные выражения и биндинг параметров.

Comment: Вообще если вы таки делаете редактирование, то в случае post-запроса изменяете, а вот в случае get видимо надо выбрать все же данные из таблицы, и подставить в форму редактирования.

Comment: @teran добавил  id как скрытую `<input type = "hidden", name = "id", value = "".$row["id"] >`, но она остается неопределенной в строке с запросом

Comment: дак может получить ее из `$_POST['id']` ?

Comment: `$_POST['submit']` никогда не придёт, потому что он не отправляется формой. `&LastName` - крутое определение переменной, но нет. `$id` - телепортировался из другого файла не иначе. Вы ещё спрашиваете почему не работает?